# is SharePoint Rest API safe to publish?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Is publishing /_api in a production environment to be utilized with authentication is safe?

if not are there ways to secure.

Answer (score 2):

The REST API is secured with the user's credentials used to make the REST call. The user can't use REST to delete a site if they don't already have permissions to delete a site via the browser UI. So it depends on who or what is making the REST call and the credentials they are using.

One of the big challenges to the REST API is learning to work with credentials.

Comment: Thank you...i will figure out how to authenticate a user using NTLM with Rest API